# Kotlin Dependency Injection Framework Choose

Tags: android, api, kotlin, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a question. I have an application that I wrote by extracting data from Api. And I want to add dependency injection to it. Which library will work best and why? How should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger hilt library is best for dependency injection very less code for injection you can simply inject anything also no need to provide any view model factories for your view models

Answer (score 1):

In Android there are multiple libraries to support dependency injection here are few of most used ones by developers.

The ones provided by google are Dagger and Hilt. But they have a bigger learning curve compared to other DI libraries. Still I would recommend to you these in your project.

Hilt is the latest counterpart and is a written over the existing Dagger DI and comes with all the abilities of Dagger hence it is recommended from now on over dagger since it provides a standard way to use DI in your application which was missing in Dagger.

[Check out about Dagger from this link](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-basics)

[Check out about Hilt from this link](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

Both the above DI libraries automatically generates code that mimics the code you would have written manually to provide dependency. The code is generated at compile time and therefore if there comes any issue with providing dependency it will be shown at compile time hence avoiding runtime issues regarding fulfilling dependencies.

There are Kotlin specific dependency injection libraries too such as Koin which is more easy to learn and implement compared to Dagger.

[Check out about Koin from this link](https://insert-koin.io/)

Koin is usually considered for small to medium sized projects while Dagger and Hilt is considered for medium to large sized projects.

Comment: The Koin was the lowest efficient library of all, but thank you for the information.